# Spring - Maven | Jasper dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, jasper-reports, pom.xml

I'm trying to add my spring project the jasper dependency but i'm getting this error below
I already tried with diferent versions of jasper and log4j but i cant get it working:
I use the latest version of spring and oracle weblogic 11g.
This only happens when i add jasper dependency.
Anyone had the same problem?

```
 <1/Mai/2012 16H10m BST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:849)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:773)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 


<1/Mai/2012 16H10m BST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <name>myProject</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.3</jackson.version>
    <validation-api-version>1.0.0.GA</validation-api-version>
    <hibernate-validator-version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate-validator-version>
    <jasper.version>4.5.0</jasper.version>
    <commons.digester.version>2.1</commons.digester.version>
    <commons.collections.version>3.2.1</commons.collections.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mysql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysqljdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- validation -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>${validation-api-version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-validator-version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Data Mapper package is a high-performance data binding package built on Jackson JSON processor -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson is a high-performance JSON processor (parser, generator) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
          <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
      <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tiles-freemarker</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tiles-velocity</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tiles-ognl</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tiles-mvel</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

I checked the dependency hierarchy at pom.xml and i found something strange, I'll put below
This might be the problem? But it's weird because it only happens every time I add the dependencies of jasper. I have developed other things and never had conflicts .

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/151/capturar1b.jpg/]

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/696/capturar2f.jpg/]

Answer (score 0):

**SECOND ANSWER**

---

The first error indicates that an incompatible XML parser implementation is getting used.  Most likely Weblogic provides it's own implementation, and that is conflicting with an XML parser implementation being brought in by one of your dependencies. You need to figure out what is bringing in an XML parser, and then exclude that parser. Many IDEs (like Eclipse when using m2eclipse) can provide a visual graph of your POM to help figure the dependencies out. Alternatively, I think you can use '[mvn dependency:tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)'.

The second error *seems* to indicate that `org.apache.log4j.LogManager` is not on the classpath. Assuming you are correctly building the war (or exploded war) and all of the maven produced dependency jars are in the /WEB-INF/lib folder, then my best guess would be that there are two log4j implementations in play, and they are conflicting. (Perhaps weblogic includes a log4j implementation and makes it available to webapps by default.)  To test that, you might try setting the log4j dependency scope to "provided".  If you continue to have problems with log4j, you might consider using slf4j's own logging implementation ([logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)) instead. i.e.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

**FIRST ANSWER** (Perhaps useful, but doesn't address main issue.)

---

Try excluding commons-logging from jasper.

Also, I noticed you are using Jackson directly. Jasper also has a dependency on Jackson. In my case, I need to exclude Jackson from Jasper as well so I could reference a much newer version.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      </exclusion>        
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

I see that you did remove commons-logging from a number of other dependencies correctly. If you check that final transitive dependencies, you should not see a commons-logging.jar.

(Also, I tried improved formatting of your XML a little. It was very difficult to read previously. Still not that easy to read, but better.)

Comment: I tried your sugestion but doesn't work. What do you mean with i excluded log4j from commons-logging? Sorry but i'm just starting with maven and spring

Comment: My mistake. I originally thought you were somehow trying to exclude log4j from commons-logging, but I see now that you are not. I edited my answer to provide some more ideas on two error messages specifically.